# jQuery datepicker code change for ADA compliance

Tags: jquery, datepicker, accessibility

We are using jQuery date-picker in our application. Now, in order to meet ADA compliance, we have to change date-picker code so that it can be accessible via keyboard only (pressing Tab); right now it's only accessible via mouse click.

Is there any way we can change the existing jQuery date-picker javascript to make it accessible via keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an older but still very good example of an accessible jQuery datepicker here: https://dequeuniversity.com/library/aria/date-pickers/sf-date-picker

Also somewhat related is this blog post describing very similar (but not identical) techniques: https://www.deque.com/blog/accessible-jquery-ui-datepicker/

And finally, here's a discussion thread at WebAIM discussing this technique: https://webaim.org/discussion/mail_thread?thread=6156

Another option would be to do away with the datepicker altogether and just use simple text inputs or dropdown fields. You could even use the native HTML5 [validation techniques](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation) with regular expressions.